# How to address several objects named in the same structure in R?

Tags: r, naming-conventions, stata, abbreviation

I'd like to know how to include every object that fulfils certain naming requirements in my arguments in R. Let's say the objects are all called something like this

```
var01 var02 var03 var04 varnn
```

What I would do in Stata for instance would be simply this

```
tab1 var*
```

and it would tabulate every variable with the first 3 letters "var".

In an earlier version of this post I was quite vague about what I actually want to do in my R project. So here goes. I've got a for loop, that iterates over 650 instances, with the goal of appending 6 datasets for every one of these instances. However, for some (I don't know which), not all 6 datasets exist, which is why the rbind command that's written like this fails:

```
rbind(data01, data02, data03, data04, data05, data06)
```

I'd therefore like to run something like this

```
rbind(data*)
```

So as to account for missing datasets. 
Sorry for the confusion, I wasn't being clear enough when I originally wrote the question.

Just for reference, here is the whole loop:

```
for(i in 1:650){
  try(part1 <-  read.csv(file = paste0("Twitter Scrapes/searchTwitter/09July/",MP.ID[i],".csv")))
  try(part2 <-  read.csv(file = paste0("Twitter Scrapes/userTimeline/08July/",MP.ID[i],".csv")))
  try(part3 <-  read.csv(file = paste0("Twitter Scrapes/userTimeline/16July/",MP.ID[i],".csv")))
  try(part4 <-  read.csv(file = paste0("Twitter Scrapes/searchTwitter/17July/",MP.ID[i],".csv")))
  try(part5 <-  read.csv(file = paste0("Twitter Scrapes/userTimeline/24July/",MP.ID[i],".csv")))
  try(part6 <-  read.csv(file = paste0("Twitter Scrapes/searchTwitter/24July/",MP.ID[i],".csv")))
  allParts <- ls(pattern = "^part*")
  allNames <- paste(allParts, collapse = ", ") # this is just what I tried just now, didn't work though
  combined.df <- rbind(ALL THE DATASETS WITH PART)) 
}
```

Comment: Then from your example you would want them all.

Comment: Your `tab` example would not work in Stata. `tabulate` takes one or two variables. An example that would work is `list var*`.

Comment: ok, sorry, tab1 would work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Data**

```
var01 <- sample(2, 10, TRUE)
var02 <- sample(2, 10, TRUE)
var03 <- sample(2, 10, TRUE)
vvv01 <- sample(2, 10, TRUE) # variable which should not be tabulated
```

**Code**

```
allV <- ls(pattern = "^var.*") # vector of all variables starting with 'var'
lapply(allV, function(.) table(get(.)))
```

**Explanation**

With `ls` you get all variables which are named according to the pattern you provide. Then, you loop over all these variables, retrieve the variable by its name and tabulate it.

**Update**

With your recent changes what I would do is the following:

```
allV <- lapply(ls(pattern = "^part.*"), get) #stores all part variables in a list
combined.df <- do.call(rbind, allV) # rbinds all of them
```